# Unbeleivable, same Javascript code do not behave the same way in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I wrote the same code in two JSFiddle, and they do not behave the same way :

**HTML:**

```
<p id='complete'></p>
```

**JS:**

```
document.onreadystatechange=fnStartInit; 
function fnStartInit() 
{
  var state = document.readyState
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') 
  {
      document.getElementById('complete').innerHTML = 'Document completely loaded'
  }
}
```

**Working JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/toujsz7n/9/

**Non working JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/3sLcpa0y/7/

Why do they not behave the same way?

Comment: You have selected different options in *"Load Type"* dropdown

Comment: call fnStartInit(); probably onreadystatechange is deprecated for new version

Comment: @Nijat Aliyev: Source ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first link has the load setting "No wrap - bottom of `<head>`".

[image]

This is equivalent to having HTML like

```
<head>
<script>
// YOUR SCRIPT HERE
</script>
<head>
<body>
// YOUR HTML HERE
</body>
```

Your second link has the load setting "On Load":

[image]

This is equivalent to having HTML like

```
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
// YOUR SCRIPT HERE
}
</script>
<head>
<body>
// YOUR HTML HERE
</body>
```

You can see this if you Inspect the iframe in the lower right. So by the time the second script runs, `readystatechange` never fires again, so `fnStartInit` never runs.

Here's a Stack Snippet demonstrating the same problem:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  console.log('onload');
  document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    console.log('ready state just changed');
  };
};
```